# Problem with WordPress site migration using WP-All-In-One Migration

Tags: wordpress, migration

i have recently migrated my site from https://praticezite.com/ onto a new hosting site with the domain https://xn--klarupspark-mgb.dk. However, even though the sites from https://praticezite.com/ (/omklarupsopark, /billeder .. etc) is accessible on https://xn--klarupspark-mgb.dk, it seems like its old sites is still there and is the standard sites. I cant figure out why this is the case, can someone help me?

The blog I need help with is: xn--klarupspark-mgb.dk

Comment: I think we need a little more explanation of the problem - eg. what do you *want* to be happening that is not happening?

Comment: I want the site to use the pages which i have migrated, instead of the old pages that was on the website before the migration. The pages that you see right now when visiting the site is the design. But if you visit https://xn--klarupspark-mgb.dk/billeder/ you see the new design. I don't understand why the old pages is still there.

Comment: Ah that sounds like you migrated the files but not the database.  Can you share what steps you used with WP all in one?

Comment: Ofcourse, i exported to a .wpress file from the old site, and imported this on the new site. I then saved the permalinks twice. I thought the database was overwritten during the import

Comment: I would expect the same. I would try it again and double check the options at each step.  You could also try another plugin, like wp staging.  You could also turn on debug mode on both sites to help reveal if something is going wrong during either export or import.